# How to recursively add after increasing index?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, overloading, helper

I'm currently working on a homework assignment and the goal is to only do this recursively (no loops). I am pretty sure I can overload and add helper methods, that's the only way I can see myself finishing this.

So the problem is, I have an int array A = {1,2,3,4} (or something like that) and I need to make a returned array with {10,9,7,4}

> 10 = 1+2+3+4
>
> 9 = 2+3+4
>
> 7 = 3+4
>
> 4 = 4

I thought of using something like this (not working code)

```
int counter = 0;
public int[] r(int[] numbers){
    return r(number, counter);
}

public int[] r(int[] numbers, int index){
    int sum = 0;
    // base case to check if next value exists otherwise end it
    
    // this would be a helper method instead of a for loop
    for(int x=index; x<numbers.length; x++){
        sum += numbers[x];
    }
    
    numbers[index] = sum;
    index++;
    return r(numbers, index);
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to go about it. It is also my first week with recursion so it is kind of confusing for me. I get the right array but I have an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on numbers[index] = sum and on my return statement return r(numbers, index) and I'm not sure how to fix it. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't see a stop condition here, you kinda need one...

Comment: Your question is fine. You could point out more explicit, that you are hunting an Index Out of Bounds problem with your recursion. But otherwise well formulated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will give you the right answer:

```
public static int[] slideAndSumArrayElements(int[] array, int[] result, int index) {
    // base case - stop when the index is same as the array.length
    if (index == array.length) {
        return result;
    } 
    else {
        // Add all elements of the array starting from the index position till length of the array and store the result in result[index]
        result[index] = addArrayElementsRecursively(array, index);

        // slide the main array by incrementing the index 
        return slideAndSumArrayElements(array, result, index + 1);
    }
}

public static int addArrayElementsRecursively(int[] arr, int index){
    // base case - when the index is same as the original array len stop
    if (arr.length == index){
        return 0;
    }

    // add progressively each element of the given array 
    return arr[index] + addArrayElementsRecursively(arr, index + 1);
}

public static void arraySum(){
    int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int[] result = new int[array.length];

    result = slideAndSumArrayElements(array, result, 0);
}
```

Output array or result will be:
    [10, 9, 7, 4]

Comment: Check the comments inline and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 1):

You need a stop condition, and a way to retrieve the array afterwards

```
public int sum(int old, int[] numbers, int index) {
    if (index == numbers.length) return old;
    return sum(numbers[index] + old, numbers, index + 1);
}

public int[] r(int[] numbers, int[] output, int count) {
    if (count == numbers.length) {
        return output;
    } else {
        output[count] = sum(0, numbers, 0);
        return r(numbers, output, count + 1);
    }
}

public int[] r(int[] numbers) {
    return r(numbers, new int[numbers.length], 0);
}
```

**EDIT**: Changed code to remove the need of a `for` loop

Comment: @Joe You don't actually need a for loop though. There's a clever trick here.

Comment: @Joe No, it's even simpler than that.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is incorect

```
public int[] r(int[] numbers, int index){

    //--> needs a stop condition e.g. index==numbers.length, index==0

    int sum = 0;
    // base case to check if next value exists otherwise end it

    // this would be a helper method instead of a for loop
    for(int x=index; x<numbers.length; x++){
        //--> numbers has been overwritten by the sum 
        // you should just do numbers[index] = numbers[index-1]+numbers[index]
        // this is opposite to the summation you wish for which starts adding 
        // from the last position
        sum += numbers[x];
    }


    numbers[index] = sum;
    index++;
    return r(numbers, index);
}
```

A correct solution of your function would be

```
public int[] r(int[] numbers, int index){

    if (index == 0) {
          return numbers;
    }else{
        numbers[index] = numbers[index+1] + numbers[index]
        return r(numbers,index-1);
    }

    public int[] r(int[] numbers){
        return r(numbers, numbers.length);
    }
```

But you lose the initial array since you overwrite it

OR

You can build a function like this

```
public int sumRecursive(int[] input, int[] output,int pos){
    if (pos==0){
        output[pos] = input[pos]
        return input[pos]
    }else{
        output[pos] = input[pos] + sumRecursive(input,output,pos-1);
        return output[pos];
     }
}
```

And you need to call it like this

```
int[] output = new int[input.length];
sumRecursive(input,output,input.length);
```